# Why does "I wake up in the morning." sound better than "I wake up in morning"?

Tags: word-usage, articles

I'm confused because some of my friend said the latter while I use the former.

Comment: It's not about sound, it's about being idiomatic.

Comment: One sounds better in English than the other because one is English and the other is not. I do not understand the question.

Comment: If you spoke the second, you might get condolences.

Comment: "The" is vastly overused in English language. It can almost always be eliminated without affecting meaning. It acts as a buffer, like umm, err, or like. Excessive usage is a good way to get your 900 word essay up to 1000 words.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger You may or may not be right about the definite article being overused (I don't agree as it happens) but it should definitely _not_ be omitted in this case. No native speaker would say "I get up in morning", "I go to bed in evening" or "I work in day". As to _why_ we use the definite article I don't have a good answer which is why I've upvoted the question.

Comment: @BoldBen As a native speaker, I speak like that. 30 years I Biochemist, and it's work to put enough 'the's in a manuscript to satisfy readers. Some say it's something along *the* autism axis. They might be right. However, 'the' really does seem to be used as a space-filler, or to gain a little extra time in sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The only correct form is the one with the definite article.

Just look at [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=In%20morning%2C%20in%20the%20morning%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIn%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20morning%3B%2Cc0).

It can be explained by the rule of using the definite article with the only thing.

As there is only one morning in the day we must use 'the'.

No article is used with singular forms of countable nouns only in set-up expressions and idioms (by bus, on foot, etc.).

Comment: _By bus_ and similar aren’t really idioms (by which I think you mean idiomatic expressions more than true idioms). Modes of transportation generally take no article, except when considered as a specific, unique physical item (i.e., “I came by bus” = _bus_ is the type of transportation used; “I came on the bus” = _bus_ is the physical vehicle with wheels and doors in which you were located).

Answer (score 0):

Usage of articles and prepositions is, I think, more or less beyond logic.

> a. *I wake up in the morning.*
>
> b. **I wake up in morning.*
>
> c. *I wake up in the night.*
>
> d. **I wake up in night.*

But note:

> e. *I wake up at night.*
>
> f. **I wake up at the night.*

Go figure.